# Itamaeのsysctlの値を変更する方法に execute を使わずに済む方法

Tags: itamae, provisioning

`Itamae`を使ってIPのフォワーディングを有効にするために

```
execute 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
execute 'sysctl -e -p'
```

と `execute` リソースを使って設定を行ったのですが、できるだけ`execute`は使わずに設定をして行きたく思っています。何かもっと良い方法はありますか？

Comment: オフトピっぽいので回答じゃなくてコメントにしますがChefであればProviderにするのが良さそうかなと思いました。あと`execute`を使いたくない理由が分かれば他に回答が付くかもしれません。

Comment: Providerがよくわかってないので調べてみましたが、具体的にどのようなものなのかやっぱりわかりませんでした…。`Chef`の学習中に`execute`を多用するのは冪等性の観点からも問題が起きやすいのと、executeならシェルスクリプトと変わらないとの事で使用はできるだけ避けるようにすべきだとどこかで読んだのでそれに従っています。

Comment: 既存のResourceがない場合は 独自にResourceを作って、レシピでは作成したResourceを使うという方法があります。、その際は LWRP で Provider を書いて リポジトリに入れます。冪等性はProviderで担保されるように作るのがChefの流儀ですね。Itamaeがよくわからないのですが LWRPで調べると色々出て来ると思います。

Comment: 前のコメントはChefなのでオフトピでしたね…。Itamaeのドキュメント見てみましたがProviderについては書かれておらずDefinitionsかResource Pluginにするのが Itamaeの流儀っぽいです。

Comment: 色々とありがとうございます。 Resource Pluginの作成サンプルなどを触ってみることにします。